# Why do functions inside functional components have no access to props?

Tags: react-hooks, react-props, react-functional-component

I want to change a string on click and I'm passing the string as prop to the component. When I'm accessing the prop in the function component it works and I can see the string in the console but in the function (here testFunction) it is undefined. What is causing the problem and how to solve it?

[Here is an image of my code

```js
function Diagram({ inputCases, ...props }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  console.log("from component", inputCases);

  const testFunction = (inputCases) => {
    console.log("From the test Function", inputCases);
  };

  testFunction();
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N8GF.png)

Comment: you have `inputCases` as a parameter to the function, this will take precedence over the prop passed into the component in terms of function scope. 

If you want to use `inputCases` from the component props, remove it from the parameter of the function.   `const testFunction = () => { console.log(inputCases)}`

Comment: To add, it's not necessary to declare `inputCases` in `testFunction` thanks to [lexical scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#lexical_scoping), which allows you to use a variable outside of a function as long as it has been declared within the same scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overriding your props by function argument which name same as original props. Try this way:

```js
//without parameter
const testFunction = () => { 
    console.log("From the test Function", inputCases);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right, didn't see that.